# PHP else if into arrays?

Tags: php

OK, let's say I have this small snippit of a bunch of else-ifs in PHP

```
function getLevelByExp($theExp) {

    if ($theExp < 83) { $theLevel = 1; }
else if ($theExp < 175) { $theLevel = 2; }
else if ($theExp < 278) { $theLevel = 3; }
else if ($theExp < 392) { $theLevel = 4; }
else if ($theExp < 519) { $theLevel = 5; }
else if ($theExp < 659) { $theLevel = 6; }
else if ($theExp < 814) { $theLevel = 7; }
else if ($theExp < 987) { $theLevel = 8; }
else if ($theExp < 1178) { $theLevel = 9; }
else if ($theExp < 1390) { $theLevel = 10; }
else if ($theExp < 1624) { $theLevel = 11; }
else if ($theExp < 1884) { $theLevel = 12; }
else if ($theExp < 2172) { $theLevel = 13; }
else if ($theExp < 2492) { $theLevel = 14; }
else if ($theExp < 2845) { $theLevel = 15; }
else if ($theExp < 3237) { $theLevel = 16; }
else if ($theExp < 3671) { $theLevel = 17; }
else if ($theExp < 4151) { $theLevel = 18; }
else if ($theExp < 4683) { $theLevel = 19; }
else if ($theExp < 5273) { $theLevel = 20; }
else if ($theExp < 5926) { $theLevel = 21; }
else if ($theExp < 6650) { $theLevel = 22; }
else if ($theExp < 7451) { $theLevel = 23; }
else if ($theExp < 8339) { $theLevel = 24; }
else if ($theExp < 9322) { $theLevel = 25; }
else if ($theExp < 10412) { $theLevel = 26; }
else if ($theExp < 11618) { $theLevel = 27; }
else if ($theExp < 12955) { $theLevel = 28; }
else if ($theExp < 14436) { $theLevel = 29; }
else if ($theExp < 16076) { $theLevel = 30; }
else if ($theExp < 17893) { $theLevel = 31; }
else if ($theExp < 19906) { $theLevel = 32; }
else if ($theExp < 22137) { $theLevel = 33; }
else if ($theExp < 24607) { $theLevel = 34; }
else if ($theExp < 27345) { $theLevel = 35; }
else if ($theExp < 30377) { $theLevel = 36; }
else if ($theExp < 33737) { $theLevel = 37; }
else if ($theExp < 37460) { $theLevel = 38; }
else if ($theExp < 41584) { $theLevel = 39; }
else if ($theExp < 46154) { $theLevel = 40; }
else if ($theExp < 51217) { $theLevel = 41; }
else if ($theExp < 56827) { $theLevel = 42; }
else if ($theExp < 63042) { $theLevel = 43; }
else if ($theExp < 69929) { $theLevel = 44; }
else if ($theExp < 77560) { $theLevel = 45; }
else if ($theExp < 86015) { $theLevel = 46; }
else if ($theExp < 95383) { $theLevel = 47; }
else if ($theExp < 105764) { $theLevel = 48; }
else if ($theExp < 117266) { $theLevel = 49; }
else if ($theExp < 130010) { $theLevel = 50; }
else if ($theExp < 144132) { $theLevel = 51; }
else if ($theExp < 159781) { $theLevel = 52; }
else if ($theExp < 177120) { $theLevel = 53; }
else if ($theExp < 196333) { $theLevel = 54; }
else if ($theExp < 217623) { $theLevel = 55; }
else if ($theExp < 241215) { $theLevel = 56; }
else if ($theExp < 267356) { $theLevel = 57; }
else if ($theExp < 296323) { $theLevel = 58; }
else if ($theExp < 328421) { $theLevel = 59; }
else if ($theExp < 363990) { $theLevel = 60; }
else if ($theExp < 403404) { $theLevel = 61; }
else if ($theExp < 447078) { $theLevel = 62; }
else if ($theExp < 495475) { $theLevel = 63; }
else if ($theExp < 549104) { $theLevel = 64; }
else if ($theExp < 608531) { $theLevel = 65; }
else if ($theExp < 674384) { $theLevel = 66; }
else if ($theExp < 747357) { $theLevel = 67; }
else if ($theExp < 828220) { $theLevel = 68; }
else if ($theExp < 917826) { $theLevel = 69; }
else if ($theExp < 1017122) { $theLevel = 70; }
else if ($theExp < 1127154) { $theLevel = 71; }
else if ($theExp < 1249084) { $theLevel = 72; }
else if ($theExp < 1384199) { $theLevel = 73; }
else if ($theExp < 1533925) { $theLevel = 74; }
else if ($theExp < 1699840) { $theLevel = 75; }
else if ($theExp < 1883698) { $theLevel = 76; }
else if ($theExp < 2087436) { $theLevel = 77; }
else if ($theExp < 2313207) { $theLevel = 78; }
else if ($theExp < 2563392) { $theLevel = 79; }
else if ($theExp < 2840632) { $theLevel = 80; }
else if ($theExp < 3147852) { $theLevel = 81; }
else if ($theExp < 3488295) { $theLevel = 82; }
else if ($theExp < 3865553) { $theLevel = 83; }
else if ($theExp < 4283609) { $theLevel = 84; }
else if ($theExp < 4746873) { $theLevel = 85; }
else if ($theExp < 5260236) { $theLevel = 86; }
else if ($theExp < 5829115) { $theLevel = 87; }
else if ($theExp < 6459514) { $theLevel = 88; }
else if ($theExp < 7158087) { $theLevel = 89; }
else if ($theExp < 7932204) { $theLevel = 90; }
else if ($theExp < 8790038) { $theLevel = 91; }
else if ($theExp < 9740641) { $theLevel = 92; }
else if ($theExp < 10794045) { $theLevel = 93; }
else if ($theExp < 11961369) { $theLevel = 94; }
else if ($theExp < 13254932) { $theLevel = 95; }
else if ($theExp < 14688387) { $theLevel = 96; }
else if ($theExp < 16276862) { $theLevel = 97; }
else if ($theExp < 18037122) { $theLevel = 98; }
else if ($theExp < 20000000) { $theLevel = 99; }
else { $theLevel = 99; }

return $theLevel;

}
```

As you can tell, I can easily get the Level, using the experience points, like `$currentLevel = getLevelByExp(300)` which would output: `3`.

However, would I make it so it's reversed? Get the EXPERIENCE by Level so if I enter `getExpByLevel(3)` it would output: `392`?

Comment: From that what You have given us the user could have experience between 278 and 392 to have the level 3. So You cannot get the EX exactly. You could only get the minimum or maximum EX needed for level 3.

Comment: Where do these values come from? How did you calculate them or are they just random numbers? If you calculated them you can reverse it to get the level for a specific experience

Comment: I recommend you to use a mathematic relation beween level and exp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
// level 0: 0 exp, level 1: 83 exp, level 2: 175 exp, level 3: 278 exp, ...
$levels = array(0, 83, 175, 278 /*, ... */);

// get level for theExp
$theExp = 180;

foreach ($levels as $level => $exp) {
    if($theExp < $exp) break;
}

// output level
echo "the level for {$theExp} is {$level}";
// => 2
```

To get this wrapped up using some nice encapsulation

```
class Player

    static private $levels = array(0, 83, 175, 278);
    static private $max_level = 50;

    private $exp;

    public function __construct($exp) {
        $this->exp = $exp;
    }

    public function getLevel() {

        // find level based on exp
        foreach (self::$levels as $level => $exp) {
            if ($this->exp < $exp)
                return $level;
        }

        // no level found; return max level
        return self::$max_level;
    }
}
```

Here's the usage

```
// create new player with 180 exp
$ply = new Player(180);

// get player level
echo $ply->getLevel(); //=> 2
```

---

Thanks for the `max level` tip, @EugenRieck

Comment: I don't think I should be coding at 4AM.  I'll go sleep now.........(I think you should theExp and Level around)

Comment: @weka, since arrays already serialize their numerical indexes, it makes perfect sense to have the array index represent the level.

Answer (score 0):

```
$EXP_LEVEL_MAP=array (0,83,175,278,392,....20000000);

function lvlFromExp($exp) {
  global $EXP_LEVEL_MAP;
  foreach($EXP_LEVEL_MAP as $k=>$v)
    if ($v>$exp)
      return $k;
  return 99;
}

function expFromLvl($lvl) {
  global $EXP_LEVEL_MAP;
  if ($lvl>99) $lvl=99;
  else if ($lvl<1) $lvl=1M
  return $EXP_LEVEL_MAP[$lvl];
}
```